# error of building VM instances on google cloud platform because the existing images cannot be found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to create a VM instance on google cloud platform from cloud shell.

```
  gcloud compute --project "MY_PROJECT" instance create "test-instance" --zone "us-central1-f" --machine-type "n1-standard-1" --network "defailt" --maintain-policy "MIGRATE" --scope ["https://www.googelapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"] --service-account "MY_ACCOUNT" --image "MY_IMAGE@digest" --image-project MY_PROJECT --boot-disk-size "100" --boot-disk-type "pd-standard" --boot-disk-device-name "test-instance"
```

I got error:

```
 gcloud.compute.instance.create could not fetch resource: 
 - invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.sourceIamge':'https://compute.gogoleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/MY_PROJETC/global/images/MY_IMAGE@digest'. the URL is malformed.
```

But, I used:

```
gcloud compute images list --uri # it cannot find the image
```

If I used:

```
 gcloud container images list # it can show it !
```

How can I make "gcloud compute" find my image ? thanks

Comment: How did you create your custom image?

Comment: @SiegfredV. I used docker to build the image with a given requirements.in file.

Answer (score 0):

`--image` is used to specify the [boot image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) or its [OS Image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) for the instances and not the Container Image. You would need to use the `--container-image` flag and then specify your Container Image. Check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#gcloud) for reference

Hence the command `gcloud container images list` can see your image and not the `gcloud compute images list`